# ACF Custom fields, and Wordpress Timber front end forms

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, timber

I'm trying to create a custom form on the front end so that logged in visitors can post their own content.

Using ACF pro and Timber.

In my page.php file I have

```
$new_post = array(
'post_id' => 'new_post',
'post_title' => true,
'post_content' => true,
'field_groups' => array(26), // Create post field group ID(s)
'form' => true,
'return' => '%post_url%', // Redirect to new post url
'html_before_fields' => '<div class="foobar">',
'html_after_fields' => '</div>',
'new_post' => array(
    'post_status' => 'draft',
    'post_type' => 'vlog'
),
'submit_value' => 'Create Post'
);

$context['vlogform'] = acf_form($new_post);
```

and in page.twig, I have placed

```
{{vlogform}}
```

The form renders - but its stuck in a silly place, not where I want it. Its stuck above the html element...

Any pointers?

Thanks,
Rob

** Edit **

This doesn't work

```
$context['vf_form'] = Timber\Helper::ob_function('acf_form', $new_post);
```

but this does...

```
ob_start();

acf_Form($new_post);

$context['vf_form'] = ob_get_clean();
```

Materially, what is the difference?

Thanks,
Rob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a little late, but I've managed to fix this issue by using an argument that they have added recently. I found this googling for it, so for future seekers this might come in handy.

So, in the args array, add the following:

```
$args = array(

  'echo' => false,

);
```

Comment: Can't find this feature (anymore?) as of ACF-pro 5.7.10.

Comment: Yeah, just confirmed this doesn't work. `ob_start` solution works correctly.

Answer (score 2):

So as other answers have mentioned `acf_form()` outputs the form when it is called.

To prevent the form from rendering at the top of the document, pass over your form arguments from the controller (page.php) to the view

```
acf_form_head();
get_header();

$context = Timber::context();
$context['post'] = new TimberPost();

$context['form_args'] = [
    'post_id' => 'new_post',
    'post_title' => true,
    'post_content' => true,
    'field_groups' => [26], // Create post field group ID(s)
    'form' => true,
    'return' => '%post_url%', // Redirect to new post url
    'html_before_fields' => '<div class="foobar">',
    'html_after_fields' => '</div>',
    'new_post' => [
        'post_status' => 'draft',
        'post_type' => 'vlog'
    ],
    'submit_value' => 'Create Post'
];


Timber::render('example-view.twig', $context);

get_footer();
```

Then in your view, use timbers `function()`helper method to call `acf_form()`

```
{{ function('acf_form', form_args) }}
```

src: https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/functions/#function

I am using latest Timber (via composer) and ACF Pro 5.9.1

On older versions of Timber, I took advantage of a similar helper method (`TimberHelper::function`) in the controller which is now deprecated

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `acf_form` is also echoing when called in the PHP file. You can either look for an alternate function (is there something like `get_acf_form` that returns the HTML but doesn't echo?) OR use Timber's output buffer wrapper:

```
$contect['vf_form'] = Timber\Helper::ob_function('acf_form', $new_post);
```

... this will store the data in the `vf_form` attribute, but not suppress it from echoing until called in Twig

Comment: Thanks. I've had a look and there is no get_acf_form or similar - so tried the buffer wrapper. Unfortunately, this doesn't appear to render any of the ACF  form to the page. I've checked my console, and there are no errors - nor does all the acf stylesheet / javascript stuff appear